# how to flip x bootstrap dropdown menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking on the internet for https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php and i need a similar effect on my dropdown menu when the user `mouseenter` on a particular `li`. I was creating a twitter bootstrap dropdown menu effect with jQuery. i just want the dropdown to be flip 360 when the `mouseenter`

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2539/

Comment: `$('li > ul').animate('back');` where did you find that code?

Comment: updated fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2539/

Comment: Great, now do please edit your question, explain your issue and please post some code where you're actually trying to flip something. As a side-question... what's wrong with the DWblog article example that you don't want to use it?